# Constitutionally, what would happen if the Icelandic President is convicted of a criminal offense?

Tags: president, constitution, iceland

Under the Icelandic constitution, the President enjoys immunity from criminal prosecutions as long as the Parliament permits it.

**Constitution of Iceland, Article 11, Paragraph 2**

> *The President may not be prosecuted on a criminal charge except with
> the consent of Althingi.*

Hypothetically, if the Icelandic Parliament (i.e. Althing) consent to the President being prosecuted, and the President is successfully convicted of a crime, what happens next?

Question:

- Is the Icelandic President constitutionally required to resign if he/she is convicted of a crime (with the consent of the Althing)?
- If the Icelandic President is convicted of a crime and refuses to resign, is it possible for him/her to remain as head of state while serving prison sentences?
- Given that it seems to require only a simple majority vote for the Parliament to permit prosecution against President, would this mechanism function as an alternative form of impeachment and removal process with exceedingly low threshold?

Comment: It would depend upon the charge, I would think. A sentence of a fine for a minor criminal traffic offense would probably have a different outcome than a conviction for murder. A long sentence of incarceration would make it, as a practical matter, impossible for the President to discharge the President's duties.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing in the Icelandic constitution that would compel a President convicted of a crime to resign.

A President can be removed from office by a three-fourths vote of Parliament plus a nationwide referendum under Article 11(3):

> The  President  may  be  removed  from  office  before  his  term  expires  if  approved  by  a majority  in  a  plebiscite  called  pursuant  to  a  resolution  adopted  by  three-fourths  of the  Members  of  Althingi.  This  plebiscite  shall  be  held  within  two  months  from  the date  of  adoption  by  Althingi  of  the  resolution.  The  President  shall  not  perform  his duties  from  the  time  the  resolution  is  adopted  by  Althingi  until  the  results  of  the plebiscite are known.